# Proton decay through a $(3,1)^{-1/3}$ complex scalar

Tags: field-theory, standard-model, beyond-the-standard-model, proton-decay

Suppose we add to the Yukawa sector of the SM a complex scalar $T^\alpha(3,1)^{-1/3}$, where $\alpha=1,2,3$ is a $SU(3)_C$ index and the charges assignment means that it transforms as a *triplet* under $SU(3)_C$, a *singlet* under $SU(2)_L$ and has $Y=Q=-1/3$. Assume $T$  much heavier than the proton.

If we restrict to the first generation, one can prove that the only gauge invariant coupling is:
$$ g\, \epsilon_{\alpha \beta \gamma}\,T^\alpha \, \bar{u}_L^{c\beta} \,d_L^\gamma \, +h.c. $$
where :

1. $\epsilon_{\alpha\beta\gamma}$ runs over $SU(3)_C$ indeces and makes that combination a singlet.
2. $\bar{u}^c_L$ is the charge conjugated left(bar) spinor: we need it because $(u_L)^{T}\,C\,d_L$ is a Lorentz scalar.
3. Any $U(1)$ (except $U(1)_{em}$) is now violated by two units (baryon number violation..).

Therefore we are allowing Proton decay.
But what decay precisely?

EDIT: If I am interested in proton decay rate, I can naively estimate it in the $M\gg m_P$ approx without knowing the decay product(s) as:
$$\Gamma_p\sim g^2\frac{m^5_p}{M^4}\times (phase space)$$

Comment: Why wouldn't you just assign baryon number $-2$to $T$?

Comment: yes, it could be. My main problem concerns the decay product since $T$ is colorful and cannot be a final state..

Comment: Well, if $T$ has baryon number $-2$, $U(1)_B$ is still a good symmetry.

Comment: I am a bit sceptical about the existence of a $\mathbf{3}$ with $n_B=-2$. Have you any example?

Comment: Well, $T$. Explicitly: The way you introduce the field, there is a unbroken symmetry that is essentialy $U(1)_B$ and under which $T$ has charge $-2$. You can call that baryon number or something else, but it still is present and unbroken, and so the asociated charge of, say, the proton, is conserved. (It might be anomalous as $U(1)_B$ is, but that's a different topic.)

Comment: The problem I'm sticking to ask to find the tree-level proton decay's feyman diagram from that coupling and give an estimate on dimensional ground...That is why I'm "not considering" the possibility you told..

Comment: Assuming I was not wrong and the coupling I wrote is the only one allowed in Yukawa sector

Comment: The coupling you have converts an L *d* and an L *u* to a scalar color triplet *T*, inheriting their 2/3 baryon number. This triplet can emit and absorb gluons and nothing else! So It doesn't do much: not coupling to leptons, it does not destroy quarks to generate leptons for  proton decay...

Comment: I agree with you.. This is a problem from a PhD admission test, so I would be surprised if there are some "mistakes". But with that charge assignment for $T$ there are no available couplings with leptons..